# Is there any digraph data set that gives all directed graphs satisfying certain requirements?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm looking for a digraph dataset that can return all directed graphs satisfying certain requirements.

Following are some examples:

1. All tournament with 12 vertices;
2. All connected digraphs with 10 vertices;
3. All digraphs with 9 vertices whose underlying undirected graph bipartite.

Is there a digraph dataset that can produce some examples mentioned above?

Comment: Cross-posted at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/34425/is-there-any-digraph-data-set-that-gives-all-directed-graphs-satisfying-certain .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 154108311168 tournaments on 12 vertices and you can make them with the tool gentourng that comes with [nauty](https://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/).

The number of connected digraphs on 10 vertices is more than 10^20, which is impossibly many. That's if you allow 2-cycles; otherwise the number is "only" about 10^15 and you can make them if you don't mind spending weeks of computer time.

The number of directed bipartite graphs on 9 vertices is 414967973 and if you don't allow 2-cycles there are only 1514031 (including disconnected).  You can make them in seconds using geng+watercluster2 in the nauty package.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply. Actually, I'm a user of your [Combinatorial Data](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/). Thank you again for making all these wonderful data publicly visible. But there are only a few classes of digraphs available in this dataset. Recently, I need to generate all orientations (2-cycles are allowed) of some undirected graphs. For a graph with 15 edges, my method gives $3^{15}$ results. But I want to delete isomorphic graphs, which is quite time-consuming.

Comment: I heard about nauty before, but haven't looked into it. I will take a good look and see what I can do.

Comment: What you need is the utility "directg" in the nauty package - this orients a graph and removes duplicates.

Comment: And also $3^{15} = 14348907$ which is not a very large set to process.

Comment: @GordonRoyle I just played with 'directg' a little bit. The output format is simple text format (in nasty v2.5r9). But how to get a more general output which can be imported into another software directly, say Mathematica? Is it possible to output the results into another format say .GraphML directly in 'directg'? But I didn't see any such options.

Comment: @Han - writing a small script in your preferred language is your best option. Rather than guess the target format and write dozens of output routines all of which need debugging and updating, the UNIX philosophy is that the program should do one thing - orient graphs - really well, and any format changing should be left to the users.